# Android Gradle. How to combine Flavors with buildTypes

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors, android-build-type

I'm working on a white brand app.

We create a different flavor per client and each client has `Debug` and `Production` APIs, so I'm trying to set them up in the Gradle.

How should I do that?

Here is what I've tried:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        // some configurations
    }
    release {
        // some configurations
    }
}

flavorDimensions "client"
productFlavors {
    company1{
        dimension "client"
        buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "\"https://app.company1/devApi/\"")
    }

    company2 {
        dimension "client"
        buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "\"https://app.company2/devApi/\"")
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I would like to be able to define a different `BASE_URL` per each Flavor and Buildtype.

Flavor company1, BuildType debug

```
https://app.company1.com/devApi/
```

Flavor company1, BuildType release

```
https://app.company1.com/prodApi/
```

Flavor company2, BuildType debug

```
https://dev.company2.com/api/
```

Flavor company2, BuildType release

```
https://prod.company2.com/api/
```

Comment: what exactly are your requirements which you want to give in flavor ?

Comment: check my answer @kike , you can modify according  to your requirement

Comment: Hi, @kike, did you get the best solution now? I got the same issue today. Unfortunately, I cannot get a satisfying solution only with Gradle. I finally have to define two variables in each flavour, one for debug and the other for release. Then in the code, I check the buildType to get the right value.   Any update?

Comment: @Freddie If these variable are very different (ex. you cannot combine strings) you will have to set them in a separate `strings.xml`. Check my answer below and let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60974259/build-configurations-based-on-app-variant-buildtype-flavor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For my specific problem, where the URLs differ a lot one to another, I couldn't make it work with Flavours and BuildTypes.

I was able to define the debug/production URLs by using specific `strings.xml` for each build variant (which is each combination of flavour and build type):

These are the folder structures to do so:

```
src/flavour1Debug/res/values/strings.xml 
src/flavour1Release/res/values/strings.xml
```

and

```
src/flavour2Debug/res/values/strings.xml 
src/flavour2Release/res/values/strings.xml
```

EXTRA:
This can also be used to host different `google-services.json` files

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL_PATH", "\"devApi/\"")
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL_PATH", "\"prodApi/\"")
    }
}

flavorDimensions "client"
productFlavors {
    company1{
        dimension "client"
        buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL_DOMAIN", "\"https://app.company1/\"")
    }

    company2 {
        dimension "client"
        buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL_DOMAIN", "\"https://app.company2/\"")
    }
}
```

And use it like:

> String BASE_URL = BuildConfig.BASE_URL_DOMAIN +
>   BuildConfig.BASE_URL_PATH

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would work for some cases but in my case I need the BASE_URL all together. That URL does not depend on us and may be `company1.com/apiDebug` or `debug.company2.com/api`

Comment: My idea is to divide the whole URL into parts and put them into Flavours and BuildTypes. This works even if there are combination with more that 2 types. i.e something like Company1-Mobile-Debug, Company2-Tablet-Prod etc.. If you say everything is uncertain here, then you better go with String constants in you Java and use Build Type and Product Flavours along with some Switch statement to build the actual URL at run time

Answer (score 0):

You can use flavors to add basic configurations for your application, that ranges from `app url`, `API keys`, `master password` etc.

```
flavorDimensions "Mobile"
     productFlavors {
        Production {
            dimension "Mobile"   // dimension can be mobile, kiosks, tv, miniKiosks etc

            resValue "string", "API_KEY", "Just to give the idea"
            resValue "string", "SERVICE_IP", "Your service IP"
            resValue "string", "SERVICE_BASE_URL", ""
            resValue "string", "APK_BASE_URL", "base url"
            resValue "string", "MASTER_PASSWORD", ""

        }
        Demo {
            dimension "Mobile"

            resValue "string", "API_KEY", "Just to give the idea"
            resValue "string", "SERVICE_IP", "Your service IP"
            resValue "string", "SERVICE_BASE_URL", "services/v1/"
            resValue "string", "APK_BASE_URL", "base url"
            resValue "string", "MASTER_PASSWORD", ""
        }

    Local {
            dimension "Mobile"

            resValue "string", "API_KEY", ""
//            resValue "string", "app_name", ""
            resValue "string", "SERVICE_IP", ""
//            resValue "string", "SERVICE_IP", ""
            resValue "string", "SERVICE_BASE_URL", ""
            resValue "string", "APK_BASE_URL", ""
            resValue "string", "MASTER_PASSWORD", "a"
        }
    }
```

Now if you check at your **`build varients`** you will get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you do not correctly place your buildTypes for flavors and no correct params inside each company and also I suggest you read more about Gradle setups([developer.android](https://developer.android.com)).

```
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            // some configurations
        }
        release {
            // some configurations
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "version", "brand"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            versionName += "dev"
            dimension "version"

            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_API_URL", "\...\""
        }

        prod {
            dimension "version"

            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_API_URL", "\...\""
        }
        company1{
            dimension "brand"
            versionName "1.0.0"
            buildConfigField("int", "CLONE_ID", "1")
            **here you can set some params, for current clone id: examlpe ->** buildConfigField("boolean", "SHOW_CREDIT_BUY_IN_PROFILE", "true")
        }

        company2 {
            dimension "brand" 
            versionName "1.0.0"
            buildConfigField("int", "CLONE_ID", "2")
            **here you can set some params, for current clone id: examlpe ->** buildConfigField("boolean", "SHOW_CREDIT_BUY_IN_PROFILE", "false")


    }
```